# Absolute value of complex $\exp(z^2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, absolute-value

(This is my first post on stackexchange. Please tell me, if I made any formatting errors and such.)

This question is about how the absolute value function works with the complex exponential.

We have to determine, what $|\exp (z^2)|$ is.  Since we know that $z=x+i y$ and $|\exp(z)| = \exp(Re(z))$, after some calculation, it arises that $|\exp(z^2)| = \exp(x^2 - y^2)$.

Does the absolute value of the left side of the equation influence the right side?  How I take it, since $|\exp(z)| = \exp(Re(z))$ i.e. it doesn't. But as I said, we're unsure.

P.S: Yes, I know that the right side still needs to be calculated further, but right now, I'd primarily like to know, how the abs. value works in this situation.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Does the absolute value on the LHS influence the RHS? What do you mean? I mean, yes, if it weren't for the absolute value, both the sides would be complex in general, and not real.

Comment: Are you asking how to deduce the equation $\left| \exp(z) \right| = \exp(Re(z))$?

Comment: @PauloMourão
Yes, kind of like that. See, my fellow student's calculation led to exp($x^2$ +$y^2$), which they justified with the absolute value turning the minus to a plus.
But I think the RHS is unaffected by the abs.value. I'm sorry, if I'm wording this confusingly.

Comment: The absolute value does, of course, influence the right hand side, but it does so precisely in the way that you showed in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Not many calculations, actually. You know that, for every $w\in\mathbb{C}$,
$$
\lvert\exp(w)\rvert=\exp(\operatorname{Re}(w))
$$
If $z=x+yi$ and $w=z^2=(x^2-y^2)+2xyi$, you immediately get
$$
\lvert\exp(z^2)\rvert=\exp(x^2-y^2)
$$
You might write this as
$$
\lvert\exp(z^2)\rvert=\exp(\operatorname{Re}(z)^2-\operatorname{Im}(z)^2)
$$
in order to express the result only in terms of $z$.